# Iterate nested list structure and approximate missing values

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I got a problem which I would love some help with. I have a nested list structure, where the inner lists contains information about stocks. This data is lacking on weekends, and I need to fill in these gaps by approximating them. Approximation is done accordingly:

If a volume/price for a given day is x, and the next available data point is y, the approximation of the following day after x is calculated by (x+y)/2, untill all gaps are filled.

My container list:

```
stocks = [['Stock', 'Date', 'Volume', 'Price'], ['GME', 1, 6218300, 184.5], ['GME', 2, 4768300, 177.970001], ['GME', 3, 10047400, 170.259995], ['GME', 4, 9442000, 158.360001], ['GME', 7, 16683600, 141.089996], ['GME', 8, 6806900, 140.990005], ['GME', 9, 21138100, 166.529999], ['GME', 10, 7856800, 156.440002], ['GME', 11, 5139700, 154.690002], ['GME', 14, 10520200, 164.369995], ['GME', 15, 4658600, 158.529999]]
```

The gaps in my data are the following dates:

```
missing_values = [5, 6, 12, 13]
```

An example of my desired output:

```
updated_stocks = [['Stock', 'Date', 'Volume', 'Price'], ... ['GME', 4, 9442000, 158.360001], ['GME', 5, 13062800.0, 149.72499850000003], ['GME', 6,  ...]
```

What I've tried so far, that is failing;

```
        missing_values = [5, 6, 12, 13]
        stocks = [['Stock', 'Date', 'Volume', 'Price'], ['GME', 1, 6218300, 184.5], ['GME', 2, 4768300, 177.970001], ['GME', 3, 10047400, 170.259995], ['GME', 4, 9442000, 158.360001], ['GME', 7, 16683600, 141.089996], ['GME', 8, 6806900, 140.990005], ['GME', 9, 21138100, 166.529999], ['GME', 10, 7856800, 156.440002], ['GME', 11, 5139700, 154.690002], ['GME', 14, 10520200, 164.369995], ['GME', 15, 4658600, 158.529999]]
        for i in stock_list[1:]:
            if len(missing_values) > 0:
                j = missing_values[0]
                k = i[1]+1

                if k == j:
                    frame = []
                    stock = i[0]
                    date = j

                    x_volume = int(i[2])
                    y_volume = int(stock_list[i[1]+1][2])
                    xi_volume = (x_volume+y_volume)/2

                    x_price = float(i[3])
                    y_price = float(stock_list[i[1]+1][3])
                    xi_price = (x_price+y_price)/2
                    
                    frame.append(stock)
                    frame.append(date)
                    frame.append(xi_volume)
                    frame.append(xi_price)

                    stock_list.insert(j, frame)
                    missing_values.remove(j)

#Output
#[['Stock', 'Date', 'Volume', 'Price'], ['GME', 1, 6218300, 184.5], ['GME', 2, 4768300, 177.970001], ['GME', 3, 10047400, 170.259995], ['GME', 4, 9442000, 158.360001], ['GME', 5, 13062800.0, 149.72499850000003], ['GME', 7, 16683600, 141.089996], ['GME', 8, 6806900, 140.990005], ['GME', 9, 21138100, 166.529999], ['GME', 10, 7856800, 156.440002], ['GME', 11, 5139700, 154.690002], ['GME', 14, 10520200, 164.369995], ['GME', 15, 4658600, 158.529999]]
```

Would appreciate any input!
Ciao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an extra step, where I convert the nested list to a list of dictionaries because I felt it was easier to access the values. I am using a new function called "get_closest_stock" where I basically sort the the existing stocks by closeness to the given date and return the closest result.

I created a repl where you can check the solution https://replit.com/@beesperester/FuchsiaVariableTelecommunication

```py
def get_closest_stock(stock_date, stock_dicts):
    sorted_stock_dicts = sorted(stock_dicts, key=lambda x: abs(stock_date - x["Date"]))

    return sorted_stock_dicts[0]


stocks = [
    ['Stock', 'Date', 'Volume', 'Price'],
    ['GME', 1, 6218300, 184.5],
    ['GME', 2, 4768300, 177.970001],
    ['GME', 3, 10047400, 170.259995],
    ['GME', 4, 9442000, 158.360001],
    ['GME', 7, 16683600, 141.089996],
    ['GME', 8, 6806900, 140.990005],
    ['GME', 9, 21138100, 166.529999],
    ['GME', 10, 7856800, 156.440002],
    ['GME', 11, 5139700, 154.690002],
    ['GME', 14, 10520200, 164.369995],
    ['GME', 15, 4658600, 158.529999]]

missing_values = [5, 6, 12, 13]

# pop first list from nested list to remove the column names
columns = stocks.pop(0)

# convert nested list to list of dicts for easier value access
stock_dicts = []

for stock in stocks:
    stock_dict = dict(zip(columns, stock))

    stock_dicts.append(stock_dict)

# create average stock dates
for index, missing_value in enumerate(missing_values):
    # get previous stock from stock dicts
    previous_stock = get_closest_stock(missing_value - 1, stock_dicts)

    # get next stock from stock dicts
    next_stock = get_closest_stock(missing_value + 1, stock_dicts)

    # create new dict with averaged values from previous_stock
    # and next stock
    average_stock = {
        **previous_stock,
        "Date": missing_value,
        "Volume": (
            (previous_stock["Volume"] + next_stock["Volume"]) / 2.0
        ),
        "Price": (
            (previous_stock["Price"] + next_stock["Price"]) / 2.0
        )
    }

    # append averaged stock
    stock_dicts.append(average_stock)

# sort stocks by date
stock_dicts_sorted = sorted(stock_dicts, key=lambda x: x["Date"])

# convert back to nested lists to match desired output
stocks_including_average_dates = [columns] + [list(x.values()) for x in stock_dicts_sorted]

print(stocks_including_average_dates)
```

Output looks like this:

```py
[['Stock', 'Date', 'Volume', 'Price'], ['GME', 1, 6218300, 184.5], ['GME', 2, 4768300, 177.970001], ['GME', 3, 10047400, 170.259995], ['GME', 4, 9442000, 158.360001], ['GME', 5, 13062800.0, 149.72499850000003], ['GME', 6, 14873200.0, 145.40749725], ['GME', 7, 16683600, 141.089996], ['GME', 8, 6806900, 140.990005], ['GME', 9, 21138100, 166.529999], ['GME', 10, 7856800, 156.440002], ['GME', 11, 5139700, 154.690002], ['GME', 12, 7829950.0, 159.52999849999998], ['GME', 13, 9175075.0, 161.94999674999997], ['GME', 14, 10520200, 164.369995], ['GME', 15, 4658600, 158.529999]]
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! Great answer and explanations :)

Comment: Just one thing I find a bit confusing, what does the '**previous_stock' do?

Comment: That is python3 functionality for spreading the items of the dict "previous_stock" into the new dict. it's a shorter version of dict_a.update(dict_b) or in this case filling an empty dict with the keys and values of "previous_stock" {}.update(previous_stock)